# Keep toggled panel open after form submit

Tags: jquery

I have a contact form that is within a sliding panel and I want the panel to remain open after a user submits a form.
Current code is this:

```
        jQuery("a.button.large").click(function(){
            jQuery("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");

        });
```

Comment: Is this a jQuery form post or a post with a full page reload?

Comment: if you want it to remain open, you shouldnt call jQuery("#panel").slideToggle("slow"); (I suppose that the panel is allready open, if you call toggle on it, it ll close)

Comment: It's a post with full page reload. If there are errors, it will add a span class of "error" and if successful will add a class of "thanks". Is there a way to hook into these classes and keep the panel open?